# Vim Snippets (Ultisnips): is there a snippet for simple ( and {?

Tags: vim, code-snippets, ultisnips

Before I try to write my own, I'm wondering if there is a simple snippet for `{` and `(`?

For example If I'm writing this (my cursor is the `|`):

```
abc abc (|
```

and then press tab, I want this:

```
abc abc (
  |
)
```

The exact same with `{ }`....

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing such snippet already exists as people tend to use brackets/auto-pairing plugins instead which insert balanced pairs more simply (just `(`, or maybe `(`+`<cr>`, instead of `(<tab>`). It wouldn't be very difficult to write a snippet though.

The newline is then usually inserted with `<cr>`  that analyses its context. In lh-brackets case, if it sees the cursor within `{}`, it add the 2 newlines, move the cursor in between and properly indent. It wouldn't be complex to extend this to `()` as well. It has the advantage that an empty pair will quickly be *opened* with the cursor indented in the middle of the newlines.